# any perfomance gain when specifying property to transition instead of all

Tags: css

I've googled around but haven't found any information on whether this:

```
transition: opacity 1s
```

will be faster than this

```
transition: all 1s
```

?

Comment: Are you assuming that only `opacity` will change?

Comment: no, this is in general, e.g. `opacity and height` vs `all`

Comment: Why not test it...your browser has tools that will let you do that.

Comment: Then `opacity` will be faster than `all` because only the change in opacity will be animated. `all` will animate changes in all other properties too.

Comment: @Paulie_D, yeah, I just thought somebody has already done that and knows something

Comment: @Oriol, thanks. This question is probably a duplicate as `Steve Sanders` pointed out